# Woocommerce - single-product вывод по категории

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день. На странице товара нужно вывести элемент только с определенной категории, в моем случае у моей категории ярлык gifts. Помогите разобраться.

```
<?php
    global $product;
?>
<?php if (is_category( 'gifts' )) : ?>
    <div class="stock">
        <img class="bg_stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/bg_stock.png" alt="">
        <img class="icon-stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/icon-stock.png" alt="">
        <p><?php _e('Акция! Бесплатная доставка акционной продукции по всей Украине!', 'woocommerce')?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

content-single-product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content in the single-product.php template
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
global $product;
$category = get_term_by( 'name', 'gifts', 'product_cat' );
$cat_id = $category->term_id;

?>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_single_product hook.
 *
 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
 */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

 if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo get_the_password_form();
    return;
     }
?>

<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('product-description vertic_padd'); ?>>
<div class="wrapen">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="left-part">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
?>

</div>

        <div class="summary entry-summary right-part">

        <?php if (in_array($cat_id, $product->category_ids)) : ?>
            <div class="stock">
                <img class="bg_stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/bg_stock.png" alt="">
                <img class="icon-stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/icon-stock.png" alt="">
                <p><?php _e('Акция! Бесплатная доставка акционной продукции по всей Украине!', 'woocommerce')?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?> 

        <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gifts', true) ) : ?>
            <div class="stock">
                <img class="bg_stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/bg_stock.png" alt="">
                <img class="icon-stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/icon-stock.png" alt="">
                <p><?php _e('Акция! Бесплатная доставка акционной продукции по всей Украине!', 'woocommerce')?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
                 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
            ?>

        </div><!-- .summary -->

    </div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
    <p class="caption">вам также может понравиться</p>
    <?php get_sidebar('like'); ?>
</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
        ?>

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WooCommerce не категории, а таксономии. Поэтому надо так:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $category = get_term_by( 'name', 'gifts', 'product_cat' );
    $cat_id = $category->term_id;
?>
<?php if (in_array($cat_id, $product->category_ids)) : ?>
    <div class="stock">
        <img class="bg_stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/bg_stock.png" alt="">
        <img class="icon-stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/icon-stock.png" alt="">
        <p><?php _e('Акция! Бесплатная доставка акционной продукции по всей Украине!', 'woocommerce')?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Не получается что-то таксономией.Может я что-то не правильно понял?( Подали идею вывести это через произвольные поля:
`<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gifts', true) ) : ?>
 <div class="stock">
  <img class="bg_stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/bg_stock.png" alt="">
  <img class="icon-stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/icon-stock.png" alt="">
  <p><?php _e('Акция! Бесплатная доставка акционной продукции по всей Украине!', 'woocommerce')?></p>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Если приведенный вами код работает, то у вас вообще не таксономия (категория товара) определена, а просто в метаданные поста записано gifts. Задайте категорию товара gifts через админку и вы увидите, что ваш код не работает. А свой я проверял на тестовом сайте.

Comment: Ну я задал категорию gifts но таксономией не получается, сейчас работает через мета. Код прописал в `themes\mytheme\woocommerce\single-product.php`. Может вы по ссылке поймете что я делаю не так? [ссылка](http://demo-garotaweb.pe.hu/product/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5/)

Comment: по ссылке не поймешь, добавьте в вопрос полный код single-product.php

Comment: Добавил, перепутал не `single-product.php` а `content-single-product.php`

Comment: Я не пойму, что не получается? У вас в категории gifts `http://demo-garotaweb.pe.hu/product-category/gifts/` содержится товар фильтр розовый. А вот Барон Шейкер не входит в эту категорию. Зайдите на страницу Барон Шейкер и убедитесь, что блок "Акция" отсутствует. Мой код работает.

Comment: Не знаю почему не работает через ваш код. Перепробовал на разных страницах.
Нашел еще 1 способ вывести данный элемент. Оставляю тут:    `<?php if ($product->is_on_sale()) : ?>
       <div class="stock">
           <img class="bg_stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/bg_stock.png" alt="">
           <img class="icon-stock" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/app/img/icon-stock.png" alt="">
           <p><?php _e('Акция! Бесплатная доставка акционной продукции по всей Украине!', 'woocommerce')?></p>
       </div>
   <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Как он не работает, когда вы мне присылаете содержимое файла php с моим кодом, я смотрю на сайт снаружи и вижу правильный результат. А вот то, что вы сейчас прислали, это вообще из другой оперы и отношения к вашему вопросу не имеет никакого.

Comment: Я имею ввиду не работает у меня. `я смотрю на сайт снаружи и вижу правильный результат`. Прежде же выводилось через мой код:  `<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gifts', true) ) : ?>`. Через ваш не получилось. Я уверен что код правильно написан, и вы не раз мне помогали. Где-то я что-то просто напортачил видать. Ну по логике тот код что я последний скинул и есть акции. т.е. если есть скидка на товар то выводим данный объект. В любом случае спасибо за вашу помощь!)